# MySQL Fulltext Search: One-to-many Relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many, relationship

I'm attempting to implement a search function on a two tables with a one-to-many relationship. Think of it as a **post** with multiple **tags**. Each tag has its own row in the `tag` table.

I'd like to retrieve a post if all of the search terms can be found in either a) the **post text**, b) the **post tags** or c) **both**.

Let's say I've created my tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE post (
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    text VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tag (
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    post MEDIUMINT NOT NULL
);
```

And I create indexes like this:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX post_idx ON post(text);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX tag_idx ON tag(name);
```

If my search query were "TermA TermB" and wanted to search **just** in the post text, I'd formulate my SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST('+TermA +TermB' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Is there a way to add tags into the mix? My previous attempt was this:

```
SELECT * FROM post 
RIGHT JOIN tag ON tag.post = post.id 
WHERE MATCH(post.text) AGAINST('TermA TermB' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH(tag.name) AGAINST('TermA TermB' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

The problem is, this is only an **any words** query and not an **all words** query. By this I mean, I'd like to retrieve the post if TermA is in the text and TermB is in the tags.

What am I missing here? Is this even possible using a fulltext search? Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT post.* 
FROM post 
INNER JOIN (SELECT post, GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ' ') tags FROM tag GROUP BY post) tag ON post.id=tag.post
WHERE MATCH(post.text) AGAINST('+TermA +TermB' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH(tags) AGAINST('+TermA +TermB' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This might work to also get results that match from either content or tags, but it didn't work in the MySQL 5.1:

```
SELECT post.*, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name SEPARATOR ' ') tags 
FROM post 
LEFT JOIN tag ON post.id=tag.post
GROUP BY post.id
HAVING MATCH(post.text,tags) AGAINST('+TermA +TermB' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

so I rewrote it as:

```
SELECT post.*, tags
FROM post 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT post, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name SEPARATOR ' ') tags FROM tag GROUP BY post) tags ON post.id=tags.post
WHERE MATCH(post.text, tags) AGAINST('+TermA +TermB' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: I tried this. The only issue with it is that if only one of the terms is in the post text and none of the terms are in the tags, it still matches. I need it to be an **and**.

Comment: It was missing + for terms in MATCH(post.text). Test the updated query.

Comment: Now it only matches if both terms are in the text AND both terms are in the tags. What I need is for all of the terms to be found in the text, the tags, or both. Like say TermA is in the text but TermB is in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but I'm guessing that in your `Tags` table, you have one row for each tag per post. So one row containing the tag 'TermA' for post 1 and another record with the tag 'TermB', right?

The all words query (with `+`) only returns rows where the searched field contains all the specified words. For the tags table, that is never the case.

One possible solution would be to store all tags in a single field in the posts table itself. Then it would be easy to do advanced matching on the tags as well.

Another possibility is to change the condition for tags altogether. That is, use an `all` query for the text and an `any` query for the tags. To do that, you'll have to modify the search query yourself, which can fortunately be as easy as removing the plusses from the query.

You can also query for an exact match, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM post p
WHERE
  MATCH(p.text) AGAINST('TermA TermB' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND 
     /* Number of matching tags .. */
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tags t 
      WHERE 
        t.post = p.id
        AND (t.tag in ('TermA', 'TermB')
     = /* .. must be .. */ 
     2 /* .. number of searched tags */ )
```

In this query, I count the number of matching tags. In this case I want it to be exactly 2, meaning that both tags match (provided that tags are unique per post). You could also check for >= 1 to see if any tags match.

But as you can see, this also requires parsing of the search string. You will have to remove the plusses (or even check their existence to understand whether you want 'any' or 'all'). And you will have to split it as well to get the number of searched words, and get the separate words themselves.

All in all, adding all tags to a 'tags' field in `post` is the easiest way. Not ideal from a normalisation point of view, but that is managable, I think.

Comment: This could work if I knew how many of the terms matched the post text. Is there a way to count that?

Comment: AS this is right now, at least one term has to be in the post text, and ALL of the terms have to be found in the tags. If I could subtract the number of tags found in the post text from the number of tags expected to be found in the tags, I could pull it off.

Comment: Maybe you can add a `MATCH` condition for each of the searched keywords. In boolean mode, I think it returns either 0 or 1, in which case you can just add them up.

Comment: I came up with this: `SELECT p.*, Match(p.text) against ('TermA' in boolean mode) as a, Match(p.text) against ('TermB' in boolean mode) as b, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tag t where t.post = p.id AND (t.name in ('TermA', 'TermB'))) as c from post p having (a + b + c) >= 2`. It works unless one of the term is in both the post text AND the tags...

Answer (score 0):

You can search on both `text` and `tags`.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM post 
 WHERE MATCH(text,tags) AGAINST('+TermA +TermB' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

To get this to work you'll need to make a FULLTEXT index for both columns together.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX keywords ON pos(text,tags)
```

In Boolean search mode this should do what you want.

Comment: Issue with this is that you can't make a fulltext index that spans multiple tables. Tags isn't a field, it's a table. Is your suggestion that I also keep a field in the post table with the tags in it?